# DFT sort coefficients in Fourier Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, fourier-transform, python

On the website [Drawing with DFT and Epicycles](https://www.amritaryal.com.np/posts/categories/mathematics-and-engineering/2.html) the author Amrit explains how to make the drawing with epicycles

I am studying through this site, and I have a question about `sort`.

What is the purpose of changing the order of coefficients from `c_-100, c_-99, c_-98 ...` to `c_0, c_1, c_-1, c_2, c_-2` ?

if i sort by amplitude i get the same result as sorted image.

Even without `sort` it is possible to create the epicycles and draw.

Below are the gifs with and without `sort`.

**sorted**

[image: sorted]

**unsorted**

[image: unsorted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series was placed in the usual order of the actual series, so `c1` and `c-1` are the same things as `a1` and `b1`, they are the coefficients of `cosine` and `sine` next to each other.

[image]

With that, you start creating the circles with the lowest frequency terms (`n=0, 1, 2`, etc) and proceed to the highest ones. This is what increases the "stability" of the figure. The first circle, for example, corresponding to `c_0` (or `a_0`), is stationary as it is the zero frequency term.